# Problem in sorting xml in XSLT 2.0 any ideas?

Tags: sorting, count, xslt-2.0

**Hello I am trying to sort my xml by number of occurence of element '*answer*' with attribute '*id*' and get simply summary.**

```
<person id="1">
 <answer id="A"/>
 <answer id="B"/>
</person>

<person id="2">
 <answer id="A"/>
 <answer id="C"/>
</person>

<person id="3">
 <answer id="C"/>
</person>
```

---

**I want simply summary text on output:**

A = 2 time(s)
C = 2 time(s)
B = 1 time(s)

**In XSLT 2.0 i tried:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/person/answer)">
 <xsl:sort select="count(/person/answer)" data-type="number"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="./@id"/> = 
 <xsl:value-of select="count(/person/answer[@id=./@id])"/> time(s)
</xsl:for-each>
```

**but it is not working:**
*in XMLSpy 2008:*
*"Error in XPath 2.0 expression Not a node item"*

*in Saxon 9:*
  *XPTY0020: Leading '/' cannot select the root node of the tree containing the context item: the context item is an atomic value

Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.*

Answer (score 4):

I would group and count the items in each group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//person/answer" group-by="@id">
      <xsl:sort select="count(current-group())" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(), ' = ', count(current-group()), ' time(s).&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way, when applied to the input

```
<root>
<person id="1">
 <answer id="A"/>
 <answer id="B"/>
</person>

<person id="2">
 <answer id="A"/>
 <answer id="C"/>
</person>

<person id="3">
 <answer id="C"/>
</person>
</root>
```

I get the result

```
A = 2 time(s).
C = 2 time(s).
B = 1 time(s).
```